# Bootstrap-table, overflow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I've tried Bootstrap-table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/), for filtering and pagination.

Works fine, but when I put a dropdown in the table you have to scroll to show it.

```
<table id="ex" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>#
      </td>
      <td>
        <nobr>2015-03-03</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>
        <nobr>8 000,00</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>2015-03-04</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>433,33</td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>First menu item</li>
            <li>Second menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>2015-03-06</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>33,12</td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qr3ao2e3/

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.fixed-table-body` class has the `overflow` X and Y properties set to `auto` which means:

> auto - Should cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for
>   overflowing boxes

This fixes it

```
.fixed-table-body {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[See your updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qr3ao2e3/1/). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Kristoffer glad to help out!