# Scroll, eventhough overflow-y is set to visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table with a dropdown button.

I have set overflow-y on fixed-table-body to visible so that I don't get a scrollbar. (Thanks to crazymatt, [Bootstrap-table, overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819911/bootstrap-table-overflow))

But I still want overflow-x to be auto, because I have many columns. Otherwise the site gets really ugly on mobile devices - it doesn't fit. I need a scrollbar in mobile mode.

When I use:

```
.fixed-table-body {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    height: 100%;
}
```

...the table fits perfectly in desktop and tablet (not mobile) - and the dropdown button works as well

But when I use:

```
.fixed-table-body {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
    height: 100%;
}
```

...the table fits perfectly in desktop and tablet and mobile. But the dropdown doesn't works.

How can I solve the problem?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qr3ao2e3/2/

Comment: here is Something for you
https://jsfiddle.net/qr3ao2e3/4/

Comment: Thanks Lakshya. But if I change from dropdown to dropup the problem will appear at the top instead. Look at the "dropup" at the top. A few pixels disappears.

Answer (score 0):

z-index can solve your issue. Try using below and see if it works:

```
.fixed-table-body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
.table{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Use media queries to apply it on mobile device only.

Comment: Thank you Jitesh! But the table looks strange when I click on the dropdown. See https://jsfiddle.net/qr3ao2e3/5/

Comment: Hope you are talking about small device view. That's because your dropdown width is greater than column width and when dropdown opens it tries to adjust hence stretching the column. What you can do is set min-width to column equal to the width of dropdown.

Comment: Check comment by Lakshya if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again. But even if I change the width-settings I still get height-problem? The dropdown still shows up inside the table cell, instead of a nice and smooth div "above" everything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way. The solution is not optimal, but works.

```
$('.dropdown').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { $('.fixed-table-body').css('overflow-x','visible'); },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { $('.fixed-table-body').css('overflow-x','auto'); }
});
```